# connection closed by [ip_address] port 22 on GCP instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, permissions, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I was trying to mount a persistant disk with my GCP instance. From the official documentation of GCP on mounting persistent disk, for enabling automatic mounting disk on VM restart I should edit the "/etc" folder to inorder to add the UUID_VALUE to the `fstab.backup` file. But I was unable to edit because of the permissions. So I modified the permissions for the "/etc" folder.
For example:

```
chmod -R 777 /etc
```

Now I am not able to establish ssh connection with that GCP instance now, even from Web console and gcloud cli. It's giving me the error

```
Connection closed by [ip_address] port 22
```

How can I establish ssh connection with this GCP instance. Please help me to solve this issue, Thank you.

I tried to connect to this server through ssh from webcloud, gcloud cli,vscode...but nothing is working

Comment: When you executed `chmod -R 777 /etc` you messed your complete OS

Comment: You cannot recursively modify the permissions of the `/etc` directory without destroying the system. Create a new instance. Detach the disk from the old instance and attach to the new instance. Copy the data to the new instance. Then detach and delete the old instance and disk. I wrote an article about another type of recovery. Review the commands in `METHOD 3`. https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout/

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the fstab is in a troubled state via GCP Serial Console: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console

Also, another tick to fix this is to detach the VM Disk from the VM and attach it to another Linux VM and fix the troubled files in the mounted volume and then detach the fixed drive again and create VM using the VM (tested by me for fixing full root drives in the past).

Comment: Like you said, I detached the VM disk and attached to another linux VM and changed the permissions of "/etc" back to the default(755) and attached it back. But still I'm unable to establish ssh connection through web console or anything. Is there any other way?